# How can I get the id in routes in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have to insert 2 id in my route and I have to insert those two in my database however the first `path.id` is undefined

[image]

The path.id here is undefined

```
const {params} = this.context.router;
    const {router} = this.context;
    const {routes} = router;
    let {path} = routes[routes.length - 1];
    let {form} = this.props.timeline;

    form.TimelineKey = (params.id);
    form.Link = path.id+ "/" + params.id ;
```

I don't know how will I get the 1068. Here's how it happens in my debugger:

[image]

Comment: I assume you are also using [tag:react-router]? If so, which version?

Comment: "react-router": "^3.0.2", @Chris

Comment: Can you show your router configuration? At least the relevant part of it.

Comment: `this.props.params.<param-name>` -  Example at react-router v3 docs -> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md

Comment: @Chris edited the question

Comment: @P.Macs, I need your router configuration. Something like `<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>` etc..

Comment: @Chris the router when i opened the modal is this let path = router.getCurrentLocation().pathname
  this.setState({upload: true});
  router.push(`${path}/upload/`+id)

Comment: @P.Macs, read my message again. I need that part of your code. What you just posted is not what I need to help you. Somewhere you have defined all your routes/pages. I need that. It looks like this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#preserving-urls

Comment: <Route path='/timeline/:id' component={Timeline}> @Chris but i dont have route for upload..

Answer (score 0):

All react-router parameters can be found under `this.props.params`.

Based on the info provided in the comments, you can get the `timeline` parameter like this:

```
this.props.params.timeline
```

---

So you can do:

```
form.Link = this.props.params.timeline + "/" + this.context.router.id ;
```

Comment: not working :( it was saying that timeline cant be undentified

Comment: can you console log `this.props.params` and post the exact output in your question?

Comment: it says undefined